# Which OS for a Raspberry Pi webserver?

Tags: linux, web-server

I want to turn a Raspberry 3 B+ into an webserver, but I am not sure which OS I should choose. I have some experience with Ubuntu server, but in the internet I often read that you should use Raspbian, because it's the best one for a Raspberry. But I have also read that Raspbian Lite or Jessie Lite is also recommended. Is it right that you can use any OS for a webserver, just the LAMP-package must be installed and the OS should be resource-saving? So which OS should I use?

Comment: We are looking for performance, we do not need a 'Desktop version' to do this and therefore save resources. For this one will choose a distribution as light as possible without programs or services useless and cumbersome (that sometimes start at the boot automatically). The version of `Raspbian Lite` is the lightest version of Raspbian (you will not have a desktop but you can use SSH for admin.). Once installed you can delete any defaults programs/services you do not need for an http/https service. Also, Raspbian is Debian, and actually the version is `Buster`, Jessie is the older version.

Comment: https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_lite_latest

Comment: If you want performance numbers, that must depend on what load you're going to run and how you configure. That's out of scope for here. Beyond that, any OS should work. It's not really clear why you think the OS is relevant at all, so it's not clear what the question is.

Comment: Welcome.  There's no linux distro (desktop or no) that will "outperform" another in a meaningful sense in this context, since you will be using **exactly the same software, on exactly the same hardware** regardless.  Hence there's no objective answer, it is all about personal preferences (and we are not a discussion style site).

Answer (score 2):

Get plain Raspbian Lite. That's ideal for a headless web-server.

Comment: this answer is of a very low quality as it does not contain any sort of explanation

Comment: @MohammadAli what makes you say that. How do I explain what's special about Raspbian Lite (which is Raspbian without all the GUI stuff). What part of "ideal" do you need explained?